# Objective-C Warning RunUnitTests is obsolete. Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting this warning in Objective-C:

```
RunUnitTests is obsolete. To run unit tests for your target, use the Test scheme action in the Xcode IDE and the test action in xcodebuild.
```

I did some googling around and found a solution to add TEST_AFTER_BUILD and set it to YES in User-Defined settings. After doing this the warning is still there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you running your tests in Xcode? Does your Xcode scheme have a Test action? Are you using OCUnit or XCTest for your tests? Updating your question with this information will make it easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to delete the *Run Script* build phase that invokes `RunUnitTests` from your unit test bundle target, as suggested by the Xcode info message when it tries to build your unit test bundle.

This is the offending *Run Script* build phase, likely stuck there by a previous version of Xcode:

[image]